# Paypal DPRP is disable for live account error?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

Hi I am integrating paypal recurring payments for my website.Everything works fine for sandbox credentials but for live account it gives following error:

```
[0] => ErrorType Object
            (
                [ShortMessage] => DPRP is disabled.
                [LongMessage] => DPRP is disabled for this merchant.
                [ErrorCode] => 11586
                [SeverityCode] => Error
                [ErrorParameters] => 
            )
```

I talked to paypal and they are saying that it is already enabled there and we have payments pro account.Please help,i am not sure what is going on?

Comment: i am getting following error for my live account:
**Your version of Website Payments Pro is not compatible with the Direct Payment Recurring Payments feature.**
what should I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old version of Payments Pro (Website Payments Pro 3.0) uses the DoDirectPayment API, and then you'd have to enable DPRP (DirectPayment Recurring Payments) on top of that to get access to using CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile with credit card details.

You are apparently on the new version of Pro (Payments Pro 2.0) which works on the PayFlow gateway instead of DoDirectPayment and CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

I realize that can be a little confusing that 2.0 is newer than the 3.0.  If you're curious about that you can take a look at this article I wrote on [The History of PayPal Payments Pro](http://www.angelleye.com/paypal-payments-pro-dodirectpayment-vs-payflow/).

Unfortunately, though, what you need to do is either call PayPal back and request that you specifically want Website Payments Pro 3.0 so that you can use DDP and CRPP, or you'll need to re-build your PayPal integration using the [PayFlow gateway with Recurring Billing](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks bro for the information.I am looking into it now.

Comment: Can you provide me any reference sdk to implement using payflow in PHP?

Comment: My [PayPal PHP Library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) has PayFlow included.  You would just fill out the config file and then open up the [PayFlowTransaction.php template](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/master/samples/PayFlowTransaction.php).  It has some parameters already prepared for you, but anything in the documentation you need that's missing can simply be added to the array in the template.

Comment: I got that and I created sandbox credentials for pay flow manager,but i can't see any option in your API to send test transaction,although everything is looks good in your API and thank you for the help.

**[RESPMSG] => Invalid vendor account**

Comment: getting **Not signed up for this tender type**. Any Ideas?

Comment: This was due to the American Express card type,i was using visa test card.

Comment: Yeah, Amex has a separate agreement you have to get setup.  When you're testing PayFlow in the sandbox, though, you have to use specific test credit card numbers.  Pages 89-90 of the [PayFlow docs](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf) cover these.

Comment: Yes Andrew I am using American Express and my trasactions are in portal now,but not sure why it is not taking those as recurring trasactions.I added 'recurring'=>'Y' and other required parameters

Comment: Finally in, Thank You so Much for the help Andrew,you rock!